# Merge Columns in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with three columns

```
Col1    Col2    Col3  Col4  Col 5
---------------------------------
Apple   None    192    abc   None
Banana  Banana  89     None  bcd
None    Cake    892    aaa   aaa
```

I wanna combine two columns i.e. Col1 and Col2 and col1 and col5 If one column in none and other has value then use the value if both have values then use that value.
Is it possible to merge columns like this.

```
Col1    Col3     Col4
----------------------
Apple   192      abc
Banana  89       bcd
Cake    892      aaa
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use (if None is a string first replace with `np.nan` : `df=df.replace('None',np.nan)`):

```
df_new=df.ffill().bfill()[['Col1','Col3']]
print(df_new)

     Col1  Col3
0   Apple   192
1  Banana    89
2  Banana   892
```

Based on the update:

```
df.bfill(axis=1)[['Col1','Col3','Col4']]

     Col1 Col3 Col4
0   Apple  192  abc
1  Banana   89  bcd
2    Cake  892  aaa
```

Comment: Is there a way to mention which columns to merge as I have five cols, 1,2,3,4,5 and wanna merge 1and2, 4and 5 and have out put as 1,3,5.

Comment: @Constantine1991 it will be helpful to understand if you can add some extra columns in th example. :)

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @Constantine1991 updated the answer, does this work?

Answer (score 2):

Create your mapping `dict` , the do `groupby` with `first`

```
d={'Col1':'Col1','Col2':'Col1','Col3':'Col3','Col4':'Col4','Col5':'Col4'}
Yourdf=df.mask(df=='None').groupby(d,axis=1).first()
Out[88]: 
     Col1  Col3 Col4
0   Apple   192  abc
1  Banana    89  bcd
2    Cake   892  aaa
```